# PHP Refresh button onclick

Tags: php, html, sql, button, onclick

I have this while loop that echoes entries from a SQL database. I have an "Add to Cart" button which is supposed to remove the entry from the list and add it somewhere else. This part works, but once I click on the "Add to Cart" button, the entry is not removed right away, I have to manually refresh the page or visit another page and come back in order to see that the item is removed. I tried using the following (and few similar) lines on the onclick propery of the button, but it didn't work.

```
echo "<br /><center><input type='submit' name='submitAdd' value='Add to Cart' onclick='window.location.reload();'></center>";
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: This is the while loop that I use to generate the table. It is within a  tag which is within the .

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($song_query)) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['selected_items'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $row['Item_ID']) {
            $rowID = $row['Item_ID'];
            echo "<tr style='background-color: #66FFFF;'>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='removeFromCart[]' value='$rowID'></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Item_ID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Artist'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Album'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Year'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Bit_Rate'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Sample_Rate'] . "</td>";                
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the same page handling the add to cart functionality? or is it on a different page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, so any "actions" will be executed on the server, before the results are displayed to the user. In order to modify the page after it has been loaded on the user's browser, you have to use a client-side language, such as JavaScript. If you want to show an update to your cart without having to reload the page, then using an AJAX request is your best option. Check out the tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ and let me know if you have any questions about how to implement one :)

**Update: Force Reload**
If you want to just stick with reloading the page as is, try `onclick='window.location.reload(true);'` instead of `onclick='window.location.reload();'`. The `true` parameter forces a get request to the server. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: Yep, I tried using JavaScript using functions such as onclick='window.location.reload(); on the button but it wouldn't work. I've never worked with AJAX, but if it solves this problem, I will give it a try.

Comment: `window.location.reload();` is indeed javascript, but it's simply refreshing the page, which defeats the purpose of a dynamic webpage lol. Give the tutorial a read, and get back to me :)

Comment: Also, are you open to using jQuery? It'll make ajax/updating your page way easier..

Comment: The reason I need to refresh the page in the same fashion as pressing F5 is to immediately show the difference of entry removal from the table that is generated using a while loop from a SQL table. I don't mind using JQuery or ajax, but I am unfamiliar with using them at this point and wouldn't know how to perform such an action.

Comment: If you can show your code for the table you generate, or provide a link to your page, I can see if I can help you with the ajax/jQuery..

Comment: Also, I updated my answer for a minimal change that should work.

Comment: I tried using the true parameter to no avail. I attached my while loop for generating the table on my original post.

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5; URL="yourpage-url">

Answer (score 2):

I use a link that references to the same page

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">Recargar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only feature you are looking for is to reload the page on the button's click, the way I typically do that is onclick="history.go(0)"

But if the form button is what's submitting a form and already reloads the page then I don't see why you couldn't put the while loop after your other code like this,

CHECK FOR FORM() {
UPDATE SQL DB
}

WHILE () {
OUTPUT DB DATA
}

Comment: how are you submitting the form?

Comment: "<form action='index.php' method='post'>";

Comment: So if you are posting the form with that button, javascript won't work in that way, does the page already reload when the form is submitted? because if it does, you could use this line at the end of your php code for submitting to the database: `header("location: index.php");`

Comment: The while loop is in the form because my code makes use of the $_POST variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if it reloads, although the echoes I've set to come up on submit do come up so in a way the information changes. I literally need to find the same functionality as when pressing F5.

Comment: @TheShadowbyte Check my updated answer, it should simulate the F5 functionality if that's all you're looking for..

Answer (score 0):

not a button but a simple link, but maybe still useful for some:

```
<?php 
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
print "<a href=\"$page\">Reload this page</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use header() function to refresh a web page in PHP. The PHP header() function sends an HTTP header to a client or browser in raw form.

Before HTML, XML, JSON or other output has been sent to a browser or client, a raw data is sent with the request (especially HTTP Request) made by the server as header information.

Syntax:
header ("header:url of the page")

I hope that this can place you on the right way.